How to show labels in an apache echarts custom series?
I'm trying to create a "custom" apache echarts component that acts as a timeline for a series of events. However, I managed to do everything but to get the labels to show. Here's my script:
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));
    
        myChart.setOption({
            grid: {
                containLabel: true,
            },
            width: 1300,
        });
    
        fetch('data.json')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                data.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date));
    
                const uniqueDates = [...new Set(data.map(item => item.date))];
                uniqueDates.sort((a, b) => new Date(a) - new Date(b));
                const startDate = new Date(uniqueDates[0]);
                const endDate = new Date(uniqueDates[uniqueDates.length - 1]);
                const allDates = [];
                for (let dt = new Date(startDate); dt <= endDate; dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1)) {
                    allDates.push(dt.toISOString().split('T')[0]);
                }
    
                const groupedByDate = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
                    if (!acc[curr.date]) {
                        acc[curr.date] = [];
                    }
                    acc[curr.date].push(curr);
                    return acc;
                }, {});
    
                Object.keys(groupedByDate).forEach(date => {
                    groupedByDate[date].forEach((item, index) => {
                        item.value[0] = allDates.indexOf(date);
                        item.value[1] = index;
                    });
                });
    
                const processedData = Object.values(groupedByDate).flat();
    
                var option = {
                    tooltip: {
                        trigger: 'item',
                        formatter: function (params) {
                            if (params.name && params.value[2] && params.value[2].detail) {
                                return params.name + '<br/>' + params.value[2].detail;
                            }
                            return params.name;
                        },
                        axisPointer: {
                            type: 'cross'
                        },
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        type: 'category',
                        data: allDates
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        type: 'value',
                        show: false
                    },
                    dataZoom: [{
                        type: 'inside',
                        xAxisIndex: [0, 1],
                        start: 0,
                        end: 100
                    }, {
                        show: true,
                        xAxisIndex: [0, 1],
                        type: 'slider',
                        bottom: 30,
                        start: 0,
                        end: 100
                    }],
                    series: [{
                        type: 'custom',
                        renderItem: function (params, api) {
                            const currentData = data[params.dataIndex];
                            const yValue = api.value(1);
                            const start = api.coord([api.value(0), yValue]);
                            const size = currentData.size || api.size([0, 1]);
                            const style = {
                                fill: currentData.color || '#000'
                            };
    
                            return {
                                type: 'group',
                                children: [
                                    {
                                        type: 'rect',
                                        shape: {
                                            x: start[0] - size[0] * 0.4,
                                            y: start[1] - size[1] / 2,
                                            width: size[0] * 0.8,
                                            height: size[1] / 2
                                        },
                                        style: style
                                    }
                                ]
                            };
                        },
                        name: 'Events',
                        barWidth: '20%',
                        data: processedData,
                        animation: true,
                        label: {
                            show: true,
                            position: 'inside',
                            formatter: 'test',  // Hardcoding 'test' as the label text for testing
                            fontWeight: 'medium',
                            color: '#fff',
                            shadowColor: '#000',
                            shadowBlur: 2,
                            shadowOffsetX: 1,
                            shadowOffsetY: 1
                        }
                    }]
                };
    
                myChart.setOption(option);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error fetching the data:', error);
            });
    </script>

Here's what it looks like now:

I tried to add the table in the custom render function like this:
    return {
        type: 'group',
        children: [
            {
                type: 'rect',
                shape: {
                    x: start[0] - size[0] * 0.4,
                    y: start[1] - size[1] / 2,
                    width: size[0] * 0.8,
                    height: size[1] / 2
                },
                style: style 
            },
            {
                type: 'text',
                style: {
                    text: currentData.name,
                    x: start[0],
                    y: start[1] - size[1] / 4,
                    textAlign: 'center',
                    textVerticalAlign: 'middle',
                    fontWeight: 'medium',
                    textFill: '#fff',
                    textShadowColor: currentData.color || '#000',
                    textShadowBlur: 2,
                    textShadowOffsetX: 1,
                    textShadowOffsetY: 1
                }
            }
        ]
    };

It worked but it broke other things, and it does not have the functionalties I want that are easily configured in the label
As requested in the comments here's some sample data:
[
    {
        "name": "EVENT043",
        "date": "2010-01-01",
        "value": [
            1,
            0,
            {
               "detail": "<b>Title:</b> Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br><b>TF-IDF:</b> 0.12<br><b>Term Frequency:</b> 0.014690503460983018<br><b>Type:</b> 123"}
        ],
        "color": "#C12345"
    },
    {
        "name": "EVENT1413",
        "date": "2010-01-03",
        "value": [
            3,
            0,
            {
"detail": "<b>Title:</b> Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br><b>TF-IDF:</b> 0.12<br><b>Term Frequency:</b> 0.014690503460983018<br><b>Type:</b> 123"
            }
        ],
        "color": "#C12345"
    }
]


custom series has no property label. So you need to specify the label in the custom render function. Also it would be nice if you included some sample data for people to experiment with the code.

@MatthiasMertens Thanks for the suggestion, I have added some sample data in the question :)

depending on your use case pictorialBar might be an option. But there is no support for stacking which looks like it is used in the image. Example
